# Smarty variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, smarty

I'm trying to update a site that someone created using Smarty. The page is a member directory, wherein when you click on a member's name, the member's details are revealed. However, the person who created the page used an inline `onClick` event to achieve this. With a few hundred members, it seems like a lot of code to repeat:

```
<a href="#" class="expand"
onClick="document.getElementById('detailsbox-{$member.member_id}').innerHTML = 
document.getElementById('details_'+{$member.member_id}).innerHTML;
document.getElementById('divStayTopLeft-{$member.member_id}').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('summary-{$member.member_id}').style.display='none';return false;
">
```

I tried dropping it into a function, and calling that with `onClick`, but of course `{member_id}` just returns one number when the page is output. So all links just open and close for that one member ID.

I imagine I need to change the Smarty variables to JavaScript variables, and then have the onClick event set the JavaScript variable with the correct member ID, but I don't understand JavaScript well enough to figure it out. Any tips (or outright solutions)?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: For future reference, can someone hazard a guess as to why my question was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to put the javascript function into a object or other construct to get it out of the global namespace and take the event binding out of the markup if possible, but I'll leave those as homework problems.

javascript:

```
function foo(member_id) {
    document.getElementById('detailsbox-' + member_id).innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById('details_' + member_id).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('divStayTopLeft-' + member_id).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('summary-' + member_id).style.display = 'none';
    return false;
}
```

html/tpl:

```
<a href="#" class="expand" onClick="return foo({$member.member_id});">
```

Comment: Thanks. This problem has been pushed to the back burner at the moment, so I haven't had a chance to try out your solution yet. But I will vote when I can get back to it. Thanks again!